# Turning on recommendations and buying software in software center

Tags: ubuntu

I came from the Ubuntu family to this distro and so far I got everything setup and working just fine.  When I was considering making a purchase from the software center, it tells "failure in the purcahse process"  after the screen about "connecting to payment service".  I dont see why this wont work.

Comment: Could you run software-center from terminal, try again and post the output? That would give us a place to start.

Comment: @RolandiXor Since this is an upstream bug, reporting it to the elementary OS developers won't help, it will just create more cruft. Surely this is the right place for this?

Comment: I was thinking so to but someone flagged and I was tired lol - bad call on my part.

Answer (score 1):

From this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1084529):

Ubuntu Software Center relies on Ubuntu code names in order to fetch software purchases. Since elementary OS supplies different code names, there is a mismatch. Supposedly, this can be worked around by launching Ubuntu Software Center from Terminal with:

```
export SOFTWARE_CENTER_DISTRO_CODENAME=trusty software-center
```